# Blocking posts with URL-only titles

Tags: feature-request, spam, quality-filter

In [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) we report and flag spam on the network, and it seems that some of the spam that still passes through the quality filter, has only a URL as title, nothing else. I believe posts like this can be blocked by SE's filter: I've never seen a legitimate post with only a URL in the title (and I also cannot imagine one). Titles that contain a URL can certainly be valid if they have some more title content, but not if there's only a URL.

Can posts with URL-only titles please be blocked? That could reduce the amount of spam posts a bit.